# I have done some extreme activities

Tags: riddle

> I have done some extreme activities
>   involving parachuting, and scuba diving.
>   I have worked in a circus
>   taming lions, and juggling.
>
> And even in my house, It keeps happening.
>   When cooking some food, if it catches fire,
>   I'll jump out of the window, but don't worry,
>   I have done this so many times already.
>
> I also work in construction sites.
>   That's why I'm wearing an helmet.
>   Doing, once again, the dangerous stuff,
>   by manipulating the precious oil.
>
> But in the end, all this work, all of my efforts
>   Everything would be in vain. Then I realized :
>   It's not the work itself that's worth it.
>   It's the entertainment of doing it.

> By the way, my list of deeds doesn't stop here.
>   I whacked moles in my garden with hammers
>   and protected flowers with spray
>   to keep them from nasty bugs.

Can you guess who I am referring to ?

Comment: guess 'who', so is it a person's name you want?

Comment: I used "who" to designate a character, and not an inanimate object nor a concept.

Comment: Is that `<!>` intentional?

Comment: I used that to separate the two yellow blocks. If you have a better way of doing so, you can edit. Either way, it isn't relevant to the riddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are

> Mr. Game & Watch

I have done some extreme activities
involving [parachuting](http://www.mariowiki.com/Parachute), and [scuba diving](http://www.mariowiki.com/Octopus_%28Game_%26_Watch%29).
I have worked in a circus
[taming lions](http://www.mariowiki.com/Lion), and [juggling](http://www.mariowiki.com/Ball).

And even in my house, It keeps happening.
When [cooking some food](http://www.mariowiki.com/Chef_%28Game_%26_Watch%29), if it catches fire,]
[I'll jump out of the window](http://www.mariowiki.com/Fire_%28Game_%26_Watch%29), but don't worry,
I have done this so many times already.

I also work in construction sites.
That's why I'm wearing an [helmet](http://www.mariowiki.com/Helmet_%28Game_%26_Watch%29).
Doing, once again, the dangerous stuff,
by [manipulating the precious oil](http://www.mariowiki.com/Oil_Panic_%28Game_%26_Watch%29).

But in the end, all this work, all of my efforts
Everything would be in vain. Then I realized :
It's not the work itself that's worth it.
It's the entertainment of doing it.

By the way, my list of deeds doesn't stop here.
I [whacked moles in my garden with hammers](http://www.mariowiki.com/Vermin)
and [protected flowers with spray

to keep them from nasty bugs](http://www.mariowiki.com/Greenhouse).

Comment: I was about to post this myself. I knew seeing that pop up all the time in my searches had to mean something.

Comment: I actually played some of the Game & Watch Galleries when i was younger.

Comment: The thing about vain efforts is that the score gets reset when switching the game off.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you mean

> Charlie Chaplin

I have done some extreme activities
involving parachuting, and scuba diving.

> He wore a parachute hat in Great Dictator, and diving in Modern Times

I have worked in a circus taming lions, and juggling.

> He tamed lions in Lion's Cage

And even in my house, It keeps happening. When cooking some food, if it catches fire, I'll jump out of the window, but don't worry, I have done this so many times already.

> In City Lights, these things happen

I also work in construction sites. That's why I'm wearing an helmet.

> Looking for movie where he is up on I-Beams

Doing, once again, the dangerous stuff, by manipulating the precious oil.

> Another movie where he strikes oil

But in the end, all this work, all of my efforts Everything would be in vain.

> In many movies he ends up just as destitute as when he began

Then I realized : It's not the work itself that's worth it.
    It's the entertainment of doing it.

> He was a great entertainer

I will edit as I find more stuff to correct

Comment: Since most of the clues were somewhat fitting (while not being the intended answer), I added 4 more lines.

Answer (score 5):

Are you

> Travis Pastrana from Nitro Circus

I have done some extreme activities

> He is known for doing extreme activities

involving parachuting, and scuba diving.

> He jumped out of a plane without a parachute (but he surely must have done this with a parachute too?), dived 100ft underwater holding his breath

I have worked in a circus

> Nitro Circus is an "action sport collective" led by Travis Pastrana

taming lions, and juggling.

> He has performed these feats

And even in my house, It keeps happening.
When cooking some food, if it catches fire,
I'll jump out of the window, but don't worry,
I have done this so many times already.

> He has driven cars that have caught on fire (maybe doing donuts?) and jumped out of its window to escape it

I also work in construction sites.
That's why I'm wearing an helmet.
Doing, once again, the dangerous stuff,
by manipulating the precious oil.

> He wears a helmet as he rides motorcycles

But in the end, all this work, all of my efforts
Everything would be in vain. Then I realized :
It's not the work itself that's worth it.
It's the entertainment of doing it.

> His feats are a form of entertainment for people

Comment: Not the right answer, but interesting nonetheless. The character has no relation with cars.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is

> James Bond

I have done some extreme activities
involving parachuting, and scuba diving.

> James Bond did this in several movies

I have worked in a circus
taming lions, and juggling.

> In Octopussy is a scene in a circus.

And even in my house, It keeps happening.
When cooking some food, if it catches fire,

> I am not sure about this one, yet.

I'll jump out of the window, but don't worry,
I have done this so many times already.

> James Bond jumped out of many windows

I also work in construction sites.
That's why I'm wearing an helmet.
Doing, once again, the dangerous stuff,
by manipulating the precious oil.

> There are also some scenes destroying construction sites.

But in the end, all this work, all of my efforts
Everything would be in vain. Then I realized :
It's not the work itself that's worth it.
It's the entertainment of doing it.

> James Bond movies are entertaining.

Comment: I'm trying to imagine Bond juggling or cooking ... that would be funny :D